# Thingsboard Custom Image URL for marker image function

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

I am using ThingsBoard CE and I want to use the marker image function in my widget. (I am using a building plan instead a map).

Up to now, I managed to change the marker image for my sensors using ThingsBoard's marker image function. But now I want to provide an URL for the displayed markers.

This is the actual code:

```js
if (deviceType.toUpperCase() == 'WATER METER SENSOR'.toUpperCase())
{
  var res = {size: 40};
  res.url =  images[0];
}
```

I want to specify my URL:

```
res.url="http://ip-address/pictures/device-type-icons/Temperature-Sensor.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I managed to find:

```c
    if (deviceType.toUpperCase() == 'WATER METER SENSOR'.toUpperCase())
        { 
            var res = {size: 40};
            res.url='http://your_file_server_ip_address/WATER-METER.png';
            If_Alarm_Change_Icon();            
        }

    if (deviceType.toUpperCase() == 'ENERGY METER SENSOR'.toUpperCase())
        { 
            var res = {size: 40};
            res.url='http://your_file_server_ip_address/ENERGY-METER.png';
            If_Alarm_Change_Icon();            
        }
```